# What is the usage of intrinsic read_action_data to set more than one action data?

Tags: eosio.cdt, unit-tests

Working on eosio native testing for unit testing and find an example that only for setting only one action data value:

```
   intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::read_action_data>(
     [](void* m, uint32_t len) {
        check(len <= sizeof(eosio::name), "failed from read_action_data");
        *((eosio::name*)m) = "hello"_n;
        return len; 
     });

  intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::action_data_size>(
         []() {
            return (uint32_t)sizeof(eosio::name);
         });
```

But i want to write test for more than action data value but unable to find any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a next action value need to set the value through increment of 1 in void pointer, i.e.

```
   intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::read_action_data>(
     [](void* m, uint32_t len) {
        check(len <= sizeof(eosio::name), "failed from read_action_data");
        *((eosio::name*)m) = "action1"_n;
         m = (eosio::name*)m + 1;
         *((eosio::name*)m) = "action2"_n
        return len; 
     });

  intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::action_data_size>(
         []() {
            return (uint32_t)sizeof(eosio::name)*2;
         });
```

and setting the length to all action data type's commutative length.